# Rails controller request - grabbing nested attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to access the date attribute.

```
Meeting.where('date_year BETWEEN ? AND ?', var1, var2)
```

date is an attribute of Meeting. Date is of the datetime class, how do I call date.year in a where call?

thanks

Comment: Your date attribute is a DateTime in the code and likely in the database. If you want to reference the year in your where clause then you'll have to use a database specific function call. What that call is will depend on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
Meeting.where('extract(year from date) BETWEEN ? and ?', var1, var2)
```

Comment: Date is a model attribute of the class datetime. That means that you can ask for the variable date and call date.year to return the year in the date

Comment: what is the name of datetime field in the Model for which you have require year ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Meeting.where('date_year BETWEEN ? AND ?', var1.year, var2.year) # or whatever method casts your date/time object to year
```

(offtopic, but also, you can do:

```
Meeting.where(date_year: var1.year..var2.year)
```

assuming that year is an int)

Comment: I understood `date_year` is a column storing year, not date/datetime

Comment: date is a column, date is of the class datetime, so date.year returns the year